# Adding static header and trailer information in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and which is written to output folder location with file delimiter as pipe delimited. Before writing I need to append the header and trailer in the existing dataframe.

Actual Payload:

```
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+---+
|                  _1| _2| _3| _4| _5|  _6|  _7|        _8| _9|
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+---+
|chevrolet chevell...| 18|  8|307|130|3504|12.0|1970-01-01|USA|
|   buick skylark 320| 15|  8|350|165|3693|11.5|1970-01-01|USA|
|  plymouth satellite| 18|  8|318|150|3436|11.0|1970-01-01|USA|
|       amc rebel sst| 16|  8|304|150|3433|12.0|1970-01-01|USA|
|         ford torino| 17|  8|302|140|3449|10.5|1970-01-01|USA|
|    ford galaxie 500| 15|  8|429|198|4341|10.0|1970-01-01|USA|
|    chevrolet impala| 14|  8|454|220|4354| 9.0|1970-01-01|USA|
|   plymouth fury iii| 14|  8|440|215|4312| 8.5|1970-01-01|USA|
|    pontiac catalina| 14|  8|455|225|4425|10.0|1970-01-01|USA|
|  amc ambassador dpl| 15|  8|390|190|3850| 8.5|1970-01-01|USA|
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+---+
```

Header

```
+-------+----------+-------+---+
|     _1|        _2|     _3| _4|
+-------+----------+-------+---+
|Samsung|Galaxy S10|Android| 12|
+-------+----------+-------+---+
```

Footer:

```
+----+---+----------+---+
|  _1| _2|        _3| _4|
+----+---+----------+---+
|alex| 25|California| US|
+----+---+----------+---+
```

Not necessarily the size of the columns in the payload is equal to the size of the columns for header and footer. I have converted all the dataframes to rdd as following

```
val payloadRDD = payload.rdd
val headerRDD = header.rdd 
val trailerRDD = trailer.rdd
```

Then I have performed union of all the three rdd's  as following

```
val resultRDD = spark.sparkContext.union(headerRDD,payloadRDD,trailerRDD).collect()
```

I am unable to convert the following to a dataframe before writing it on to disk.

Comment: You cannot convert it to dataframe if you have different Rows size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`Union`*** can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns.

You can append missing columns of type `NullType` before `union`.

```
def unionFrames(dfs: Seq[DataFrame]): DataFrame = {
    dfs match {
      case Nil => session.emptyDataFrame // or throw an exception?
      case x :: Nil => x
      case _ =>
        //Preserving Column order from left to right DF's column order
        val allColumns = dfs.foldLeft(collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String])((a, b) => a ++ b.columns).distinct

        val appendMissingColumns = (df: DataFrame) => {
          val columns = df.columns.toSet
          df.select(allColumns.map(c => if (columns.contains(c)) col(c) else lit(null).as(c)): _*)
        }

        dfs.tail.foldLeft(appendMissingColumns(dfs.head))((a, b) => a.union(appendMissingColumns(b)))
    }
```

**Note**: You don't need to convert `DataFrame` to `RDD`, instead perform `union` on `DataFrame` directly.